# Referencing Error in Visual Studio while making an Android app

Tags: android, visual-studio, project.json

Here is the error being written

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/NuGet/Microsoft.NuGet.targets(5,5):
>   Error: Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0"
>   framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore. (HTherapy)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup for `package.json` file in the solution folder and ensure the framework version there is correct.

For example:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0": {}
  }
}
```